# How not to repeat array in a function to use foreach

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

This works fine, but it's goofy to me as I don't know even what to search for (or if the question is titled correctly) to learn how to accomplish **not repeating the `$slide_panels` array within the `christina_slide_in_panels()` function below it and outside it.**

Sadly, this question was closed but the answer by Steve is in the comments. The question was not answered by reading the "duplicate" post accepted answer, at least not specifically.

```
//* register slide panels

$slide_panels = array (
            'slide-1'       => 'Slide Panel One',
            'slide-2'       => 'Slide Panel Two',
            'slide-3'       => 'Slide Panel Three',
            'slide-4'       => 'Slide Panel Four',
            );


foreach ( $slide_panels as $id => $slide_panel) {
    register_sidebar(
        array (
                'name'          => __( $slide_panel, 'christina' ),
                'id'            => $id,
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="slide-widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
                'before_title'  => '<h3 class="slide-widget-title">',
                'after_title'   => '</h3>',
        ));

}


//* create the panels

function christina_slide_in_panels() {

   //======== > HOW TO NOT REPEAT THIS < ========
   $slide_panels = array (
            'slide-1'       => 'Slide Panel One',
            'slide-2'       => 'Slide Panel Two',
            'slide-3'       => 'Slide Panel Three',
            'slide-4'       => 'Slide Panel Four',
            );  

    echo '<!-- begin slide panels --><div class="slide-in-panels-parent">';

    foreach ( $slide_panels as $id => $slide_panel) {

        if ( is_active_sidebar( $id ) ) {

            echo '<div class="slide-panel" id="'.$id.'" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">';
            // id used on the toggle to get this slide in

            dynamic_sidebar( $id );

            echo '</div><!-- close '.$id.' -->';
        }
        //end endif;
    }
    //end foreach

    echo '</div><!-- end slide panels -->';
    //close parent;


}
add_action('genesis_after', 'christina_slide_in_panels');
```

Comment: Can you pass it in as a variable to the function when the function is called?

Comment: So do you only want to go through the foreach loop once?

Comment: yes, it works exactly how I intend it to work, my question was trying to address not repeating the variable within a function and the answer I was pointed to is not dumbed down enough to me, but I will figure it out.

Comment: As the function and the array are in the same scope, you can make the function a closure that inherits the array: `$christina_slide_in_panels = function() use($slide_panels) {...}` and alter your add_action call: `add_action('genesis_after', $christina_slide_in_panels);`

Comment: Steve : thank you, I followed it and I get this error:  syntax error, unexpected 'add_action' (T_STRING)  on the closure for the foreach () BEFORE the $christina_slide_in_panels = function() use($slide_panels)

Comment: As a closure is a variable, you need to add a semicolon after the assignment: `$christina_slide_in_panels = function() use($slide_panels) {...};//<--here`

Comment: You are very, very kind. Thank you so much for not making my code look like a goof ball made it.